# How singleton class shared on jboss cluster

Tags: java, spring, jboss, singleton

I have one singleton class (one that is instantiated using factory method but not spring singleton) in my application. The application is deployed on jboss cluster. Moreover the application runs in spring container. Is the singleton is shared across jboss cluster nodes? Or how to share a singleton between different nodes of jboss cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not share instances in a cluster.

Comment: Thanks for response. My question is about how to share singleton between jboss nodes. That is the reason I explicitly mentioned how singleton instantiated to make sure that it is not singleton in the context of spring container

Comment: I think, that there is no spring out of the box solution, but i am not sure. So I only answered the first of your two questions. (If this was not a question, then you should rephrase it!)